# How to configure target url for BPM 8.5.6 Standard?

Tags: ibm-bpm

I'm trying to install IBM BPM 8.5.6 in a linux environment with Oracle database.

Steps I followed to install was

- Installed the IBM Installation
  Manager using BPM PFS
- Installed WAS
  and BPM Process Center using The
  installation manager.
- Created 3 oracle schema for shred db, process
  server and performance server
- Configured the installation using
  sample single cluster process center
  file provided  by IBM. : using
  BPMConfig –create option

The installation was successful and I could see all tables being created. Then I started started it using BPMConfig –start option. That too completed successfully.

I didn't change any ports so it should be using all default ports. Afterwards when I try to access the console like ***http://servername:9080/ProcessAdmin*** or ***http://servername:9080/ProcessCenter*** or anything i'm getting a 404 error message **Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /ProcessAdmin**

Do I have to do anything else? Or what is the starting point or default url to get to process portal or admin console. The WAS admin console is working fine.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Login to your deployment manager using `http://servername:9060/ibm/console` and verify if application is installed and mapped to server. Check what is `WC_ defaulthost` port for server that is a cluster member.

Comment: Default port for WC_defaulthost is 9080. Nothing is listed in the installed app. How can i install those. or What should i be seeing?

Comment: Did you run `bootstrapProcessServerData.bat -clusterName cluster_name` ? You should see a list of applications in the Enterprise applications in the console.

Comment: Yes. I ran that now and go "Completed successfully message". Still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: We should use https protocol and the port was 9444. Now the issue is solved. I think i was missing this step as well. Please post it as an answer and i'll accept it. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably used custom installation, you have to properly initialize data calling following command:

```
bootstrapProcessServerData.bat -clusterName cluster_name
```